# How can I save each flow tab in separated .json files?

Tags: node-red

how do i do it? didn't find anything about it. I work in a group project and to easy the process of working, we need separated files for each flow.

thank you.

Comment: Hello, I also had the same thing in mind because it's easier to maintain if you work on a big project, especially if you need to merge changes. so I came up with the following module: node-red-contrib-flow-manager

See if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do this with the default storage system, the whole flow is saved to the one JSON file.

You can export a selection of nodes (which could be a single tab) to the clipboard or to the built in library, but not directly to a file.

Also since the backend can only load one file at a time there would be no way to re-run the whole flow if it was broken up into separate files.

If you REALLY want this there is nothing to stop you writing your own storage plugin to save the flow how ever you want (there are already at least 3 different versions, standard, mongodb and Bluemix-cloudant on github). Details of the storage API is [here](https://nodered.org/docs/api/storage/)

Comment: Understood, thank you very much